# tinyMCE - Move and Resize Images On Mobile

Tags: html, image, pdf, mobile, tinymce

I have a Coldfusion application that takes some content written in HTML, dumps it into a textarea, adds tinyMCE 5.8.2 to the editor, allows the user to make edits, and then a button lets you download the HTML in the text field as a PDF.

The client wants to be able to make modifications to the PDF content we provide, including moving images around and resizing them, but that's where I'm having problems.  On desktop, I can click and drag images around the textarea freely, and I get resizing boxes when I click an image.  But on a mobile device/touch screen, I am unable to drag the images around (it just scrolls the page instead) or resize (it acts like I'm selecting a text area).

Is there a way to get tinyMCE to let me resize and drag images around the content area?  If not, are there any alternatives to tinyMCE out there that might get me what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Some features, including image resizing, do not have native support on mobile browsers and thus are disabled in the mobile version of TinyMCE. You can see the full list of these features in the [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/mobile/#mobiledefaultsforselectedsettings).